# Software to track machines inventory

Tags: monitoring

There is a data center, with big number of machines (OSes: various Linux distros (Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat etc), various Windows version (7,8,8.1,10 etc), MacOS). Is there a software, that can track any changes in machine components? What do I mean?

Example 1: I have motherboard X with BIOS version A  on some machine. Somebody replaced this motherboard with a new one - Y with BIOS version B. So, when the machine will be up, I want this software to catch the changes and send an "update" request to some server.

Example 2: Let's say some machine has a GPU. And It's driver has been upgraded from version XXX to YYY, so the software will send an "update" request to the server.

In conclusion, server can provide all information about changes in the machine. Machines are being tracked by it's hostname.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [GRR](https://grr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is a remote forensics & deployment tool chain.

It is Open Source, *(Apache Licence)*, rather than the machines notifying the server of changes the server polls the machines.

Answer (score 1):

We use [FusionInventory](http://fusioninventory.org/) with [GLPI](https://glpi-project.org/) where I work. Both are FOSS.

[OCS Inventory](https://www.ocsinventory-ng.org) is an other open source solution I know of.